# How to remove abnormal words from string like '0xd46b6c46a37f4578' or 'jrLJW PUNtTLrQGZ25X4DA ' - python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which contains proper words and some gibberish which does not make any sense to reader. I want to remove the those abnormal words from the string . Please note that these are just sample words there are tons of them in string. 
Example:

> 0xe933b1dfab45d591         0xe7d363050cec0146
>   0xf5e4005d43867c48         0x1e0b75e9dff872f5
>   0xa46406ec8a4e6cdc         0x3ea14cfd28ccf8fe
>   0x750b065d3715b1c8         0x6bb50ebe411dd5da
>   0xd46b6c46a37f4578         0x15b9290f631cded2
>   0xafcfd4f9daa2187e         0x9dcc5dbad77c926a
>   AEj_0IB_BpqtlN76JnAdUQ0gWWYXEzVQrFBrGQ
>    0ahUKEwjj09PGppLeAhXUZSsKHZltBc8Q61gI1QIoBzAF

i removed extra charaters like +, - ,' using following :

```
text = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', text)
```

but i couldn't not find the way to remove these characters. Help Needed . 
 Thanks.

Comment: What determines an `abnormal` word?

Comment: can you please elaborate ? i just want to remove unreadable words from the string

Comment: what determines that they are unreadable? They don't stand in an english dictionary or what is the criterion?

Comment: Well "l33tsp34k" may look abnormal for you, but there are plenty that will be able to understand its meaning

Comment: do the 'abnormal' words all begin with '0x' and are they on separate lines as shown above? Please improve your question. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes i do understand that but but i just want to differentiate them based that normal english words do not have numbers included them. Either there are just numbers or either word . For Normal criteria.

Comment: Are the other word strings spaced like a real sentence? Or are they together, without spaces?

Comment: yeah there are other word strings but they are not like sentences .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
newtext = ""
    for word in text.split():
       if not(any(char.isdigit() for char in word) and any(char.isalpha() for char in word)):
           newtext += word + " "
```

This checks if a string separated by spaces in your text contains both letters and digits. And if it doesn't it puts them in a new string.

Comment: edited it, chose the wrong cases, now it works on my computer, for you?

Comment: that did it . Thank You very much you saved my neck.